# How to redirect www blocked (This website/URL has been blocked as per instructions from Department of Telecommunications of India.”) to Non www

Tags: redirect

I have a website in wordpress, which was index in google with http://www.xyz.in but due to some reason the www version is blocked by Department of Telecommunications of India. but the non www version is still accessible. Is there anyway to hard redirect the www version (from the DNS level) to non www version. I have tried all the possible manner, but nothing works. Please help me and share your views

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en . Check this

Answer (score 2):

**Try Access It ..using   HTTPS://...**

```
https://www.xyz.in
```

**Read This..**  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

**http to https**
  https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-to-https/

**Steps:** https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console

Comment: Can you guide me in more details. what code should i add to .htaccess to redirect all (http://www.xyz.in) to (https://www.xyz.in)

Comment: @SakashAgrawal .. First try to open you site in https://... its work or not ...check  ??

Comment: For Reference ... Follow This... Link ... How can You do that,,, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-google-search-console

Comment: I have tried opening my website with https://www is opening but its showing not secure

Comment: can you give me url of your site

Comment: @pkpdeveloper .. :)